# Do I need to maintain sequence for using PHPExcel

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel for Importing and Exporting data from and to using PHP and MySQL. I need to give a download a Excel file with column headings for entering data by user. After entering the data user will upload this Excel file and data get into the MySQL table. Here I have question -

My excel file column heading is like this

```
SL No. | First Name | Middle Name | Last Name | Class | Sec | DOB | Father Name | Selected
```

But fields in my table is in different sequence like this -

```
SL No. | Selected | First Name | Middle Name | Last Name |  DOB | Class | Sec | Father Name
```

> My question is will this create any problem?
>  DO I have to maintain
>   the same sequence for both the place?
>  Do I need to keep the names
>   of excel columns and table fields same?

Thank you all with regards

Comment: If the columns are in a different order, then you'll need to extract the data from the Excel workbook in the order they are defined there, and build your SQL Insert statement to insert that data row correctly.... but you can use `INSERT INTO <table> (SLNO, FirstName, MiddleName....) VALUES (...)` where you're listing the column names in whatever order you want, without needing to match the exact ordering of columns in the table definition

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for your guidance, Sir can you kindly give any good specif reference or documentation or tutorial from which I can know how to store the data of excel sheet to MySQL table using PHPExcel by uploading the excel file.